# Backbone showing/hiding rendered views best practices

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

New to using Backbone and have a very simple application. Basically there are `Clients` and `ClientItems`. I have a view to show all Clients and if you click on a Client you get taken to their ClientItems. Going to this ClientItems view should just hide the Clients view and going back to Clients should hide ClientItems. Now, in my `render()` function for each view, it is going through the collections and dynamically adding stuff to the page. When I go back and forth between the two (using the back button) I don't really need to fully render again as all the data is there in the page, just hidden. Where should this logic go? Right now I have it in the `render()` function but it feels sloppy, what is the preferred way of handling this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We are using a global variable `App` with several common function used across application:

```
var App = {
    initialize : function() {

        App.views = {
            clientView : new ClientsView(),
            clientItemView : new ClientsItemsView()
        }
    },

    showView: function(view){
        if(App.views.current != undefined){
            $(App.views.current.el).hide();
        }
        App.views.current = view;
        $(App.views.current.el).show();
    },

    ...
}
```

And then I use this `App` from other parts of application:

```
App.showView(App.views.clientView);
```

Comment: Looks good. I see that you create the Views right off the bat in `initialize`. Is this a common thing to do? Would you do the same with collections? Makes sense to me now since I'm only ever going to need a single instance of either but I am still learning.

Comment: we are just creating the views right away, all other stuff are created when needed. You could of course add require.js, and init view when first required.

Comment: We are using App.views.current.show() so that any additional logic with respect to showing can be performed there (there may be other event listeners that change)

Answer (score 5):

IntoTheVoid's solution is good – it's nice to have a single place to hide/show views. But how do you activate the logic?

In my experience, routers are the best place for this. When a route changes and the appropriate function is called, you should update the active, visible view(s).

What if you need multiple views to be visible at once? If you have a primary view that always changes when the route changes, and multiple subsidiary sticky views, you need not worry. But if it's more complex than that, think of creating a ComboView that neatly packages all the relevant views into one containing `el` node. That way the above logic still works, and your router functions are not littered with logic for managing what views are visible at the moment.